# Swift. Get object from within object

Tags: arrays, swift

How to access an object from within an object:

```
let test = marketDailyData.timeSeriesDaily[0] //produce error "Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<String, TimeSeriesDaily>.Values' with an index of type 'Int'"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `let test = Array(marketDailyData.timeSeriesDaily.values)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

The error message explains it: TimeSeriesDaily is a Dictionary keyed by String not int

Try

```
let test = marketDailyData.timeSeriesDaily["2019-01-28"]
```